# Any chef cookbooks or recipe for Jboss EAP 6.3?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, jboss-eap-6, cookbook

I am trying to get the cookbook of JBOSS EAP 6.3.

I am going to plan to install JBOSS EAP 6.3 on my node. 
But I have difficulties to get cookbook to run.

Do help me if you have any ideals for this.

Comment: which system do you target, what have you tried ? You may have better chance on chef mailing list than here (sounds off topic to me)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this one](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/jboss-eap) looks pretty straightforward. There is detailed info about usage in Readme.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes I did tried. but I'm not too sure for the package_url details. So I couldn't get the package.

Comment: From example it seems that cookbook needs url to archive of that package. You can grab it from here http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/ .. or specificly http://www.jboss.org/download-manager/file/jboss-eap-6.3.0.GA.zip